# how do i convert dwg file to flash (swf) file?

Tags: php, jquery, html, flash, dwg

I need to convert some dwg and dxf file into swf file format directly from client browser. This dwg and dxf file are stored in server and the converted file will also be stored in server.
I found few software for this but no plugins, and software also doesnt seems to be that effective.

Thanx..!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://www.verydoc.com/dwg-to-vector/dwg-to-swf.html

http://www.bestdwgconverter.com/dwg-to-flash-converter.html

Hope this helps you.